# How to upload files in the background using rails carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm currently using the gem `Carrierwave` to upload files to my AWS s3 account. But I will be uploading some large files, so I'm worried about the server timing out and the user having to wait. 
Anyone have any suggestions to move this to a background job and how to accomplish that? I've looked at `sidekiq` but am lost trying to figure out where to start. When I try to implement it the file doens't seem to upload even though it gives a success in `Rails`.

Comment: what are you using for background jobs ? sidekiq ?

Comment: Yes, `sidekiq` and `carrierwave_backgrounder`.

Answer (score 2):

there's a gem [`carrierwave_backgrounder`](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder) to help you queue your file uploads in the background

add `gem carrierwave_backgrounder` to your `Gemfile` and bundle it

Add a initializer file `config/initializers/carrierwave_backgrounder.rb` to configure your background processor. Something like this if you're using sidekiq

```
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  c.backend :sidekiq, queue: :carrierwave
end
```

Then, use it on your models along with your carrierwave uploader

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  process_in_background :avatar
end
```

**IMPORTANT!**
You should define `:carrierwave` queue in `config/sidekiq.yml`

```
:queues:
  - [carrierwave, 1]
  - default
```

[Sidekiq Queues Configuration](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues)

Comment: I've tried this, but `sidekiq` doesn't process the job. Instead, it just uploads normally... I do have `redis` and `sidekiq` running. @sa77

Comment: @Corey You should define `:carrierwave` queue in `config/sidekiq.yml`

Comment: From what I've seen, carrierwave_backgrounder lets you process images in the background - That's creating thumbnails, resizing, etc.  The actual upload still happens on web resources.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [Carrierwave Direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) as it bypasses the rails server completely. You can then do actual processing as a background task (I recommend Sidekiq, but use whatever you want.)